# Silverlight MVVM Where to start

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism

My company is making a big push to silverlight and I am getting everything laid out for this push.  I am investigating Prism and MVVM in Silverlight.  Is this the best way to go. Anyone know any good END to END Tutorials on MVVM in Silverlight.

Thanks

Comment: I'd leave PRISM alone until have a grasp on MVVM or MVC in silverlight. PRISM is real kitchen sink stuff.

Comment: I understand that statement but I am trying to put together a rock solid practice for my company.  Prism seems to be the standard am i incorrect in my thinking?

Comment: I found these links and they really helped explain mvvm Pre Prism.    FYI 
http://community.infragistics.com/pixel8/media/p/91949.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/12/08/getting-started-with-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike Taulty's series of Prism (Microsoft's MVVM framework) for Silveright videos  is awesome.  It took me several days to watch all the videos and do the sample code along with the videos, but it really drove home Prism.  I think there are at least 8 hours of actual video.  It was well worth the watch for me.

He starts with simple concepts in a console app, and then about a 1/3 of the way through the videos takes the concepts and starts applying them with Prism/Unity in a Silverlight app.  He tackles several common problems.

**[Mike Tault's Blog Post linking to his Channel 9 videos.](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/10/27/prism-and-silverlight-screencasts-on-channel-9.aspx)**

Here is the Microsoft Patterns and Practices (the team that wrote Prism and Unity) web site for **[Prism and Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF/)**.

That should get you started.

Comment: I am going to review this info and get back to you tonight Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3):

If it is only MVVM you are looking for and do not care about all the other stuff you get with PRISM, you might want to check out some of the smaller frameworks as well. I am using the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/) by Laurent Bugnion, but there are others as well. Here is a similar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using

Answer (score 3):

How about we start at the basics? I wrote an article specifically to address the fundamentals of MVVM: why would you use it, what is it all about, and how does it solve common problems? Check it out here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/mvvm-explained.aspx

Comment: Jeremy,
Wow quite the post.  Since I posted this question i have went on in mvvm without all the frameworks.  Just trying to understand it.  Dan's Post http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/12/08/getting-started-with-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications.aspx  Kind of Made me realize how simple it could be.  Still working with commanding, you raised some new questoins and answered some others with your post.  I appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered downloading the [Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight - October 2009](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=387c7a59-b217-4318-ad1b-cbc2ea453f40)?

It's a hefty collection of really useful examples (26 in total) and there's a great help file which walks you through them all.  I hope you find what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help - but I really struggled with the same things it sounds like you are.  I started out by learning the MVVM-light toolkit.  The documentation was a little light and scattered, but I learned a lot.

From my learning, I decided to create my own toolkit - nothing really new, but just the simplest approaches I could find.  This gave me the greatest comfort moving into MVVM patterned development.  My toolkit is available at http://slmvvms.codeplex.com/ if you would like to take a look - I have provided some documentation to get you started, and I'm working on a sample application, and walkthrough.

Good luck!